# Consulta demasiado lenta al utilizar EXISTS o IN en SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, ssms

Estoy intentando generar una consulta en SqlServer, pero dada la cantidad de registros existentes se tarda demasiado y he intentado repararla pero no lo he logrado.

El caso es que existe una tabla @TABLEENCABEZADO que puede tener o no tener una ubicación y una tabla @TABLETAREAS correspondiente a detalles relacionados a @TABLEENCABEZADO, donde igualmente puede o no puede tener una ubicación.

Lo que necesito mostrar son todos los registros de @TABLEENCABEZADO que posean la ubicación indicada por el usuario o que sus detalles contengan dicha ubicación.

En el ejemplo que he generado no se puede apreciar la tardanza de la consulta, pero si se puede apreciar lo que he intentado.

```
DECLARE @TABLEENCABEZADO AS TABLE(
ID INT IDENTITY,
IDUBICACION INT,
DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(30)
)

DECLARE @TABLETAREAS AS TABLE(
ID INT IDENTITY,
IDENCABEZADO INT,
IDUBICACION INT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @TABLEENCABEZADO(IDUBICACION,DESCRIPCION)
VALUES
(1,'REGISTRO 1'),
(1,'REGISTRO 2'),
(2,'REGISTRO 2')

INSERT INTO @TABLETAREAS(IDENCABEZADO,IDUBICACION)
VALUES
(1,1),
(2,1),
(2,2),
(1,NULL),
(2,NULL),
(3,2)

--PRUEBA 1
SELECT *
FROM @TABLEENCABEZADO A
WHERE A.IDUBICACION = 2 OR EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM @TABLETAREAS B
WHERE B.IDUBICACION =2
AND IDENCABEZADO = A.ID
AND B.IDUBICACION IS NOT NULL
)

--PRUEBA 2
SELECT *
FROM @TABLEENCABEZADO A
WHERE A.IDUBICACION = 2 OR A.ID IN (
SELECT IDENCABEZADO
FROM @TABLETAREAS B
WHERE B.IDENCABEZADO = A.ID
AND B.IDUBICACION = 2
)
```

Los índices que posee la tabla @TABLETAREAS son:

```
index_name  index_description               index_keys
IX_Tack     nonclustered located on PRIMARY IdEncabezado
IX_Task     nonclustered located on PRIMARY IdUbicacion
pk_Id       clustered, unique, primary key located on PRIMARY   Id
```

Hay alguna forma, de poder realizar esta consulta de forma mas optimizada? Les agradecería mucho su ayuda por favor. Asimismo, no tengo acceso a modificar las tablas si ese fuera el caso. Gracias

Comment: ¿Qué índice(s) tienes en la tabla de tareas?

Comment: Puedes compartir los índices en las tablas y la cantidad aproximada de filas en ambas tablas?

Comment: Parece ser problema de no tener indices o prymary key en las tablas.

Comment: @LuisCazares acabo de actualizar la pregunta agregando los índices. Ahora la cantidad de registros en  TABLEENCABEZADO es de 300,000 y en TABLETAREAS 130,000 Muchas gracias

Comment: @Sal acabo de agregar los índices y la cantidad de registros. Muchas gracias

Comment: Haciendo una prueba con la estructura de tablas y la cantidad de filas, me regresa los resultados en 1 segundo. Puede ser demasiado si tiene muchas ejecuciones, pero no es malo realmente.

Comment: Prueba así: `IN (SELECT IDENCABEZADO FROM @TABLETAREAS WHERE IDUBICACION = 2)` mejora algo tu consulta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar una sub-consulta haz JOIN:

```
SELECT E.ID
     , E.IDUBICACION
     , E.DESCRIPCION
  FROM @TABLEENCABEZADO E
    LEFT JOIN @TABLETAREAS T
      ON T.IDENCABEZADO = E.ID
  WHERE E.IDUBICACION = 2
     OR T.IDUBICACION = 2
  GROUP BY E.ID
         , E.IDUBICACION
         , E.DESCRIPCION
```

Si no hay índice sobre `@TABLETAREAS.IDENCABEZADO` es totalmente legítimo solicitar su creación.

Comment: Esta consulta puede traer filas duplicadas y puede ser aún más lenta.

Comment: @Luis Veré con interés tu mejor propuesta.